# How do I handle user configuration in my package?

Tags: typescript, configuration

I am building an NPM package using TypeScript. I want to only expose one function as the public API, where users (other developers who installed the package) can interact with my package.

Users can set specific configuration options, which all the function in my package need to access in order to process the right result.

### Example

This is a simplified example, but the idea is the same. I want to allow users to set the option `acceptZero`, and have it available in every function call that the public API (`myPackage()`) makes.

```js
function add(number1: number, number2: number): number {
    if (!this.acceptZero() && (number1 === 0 || number2 === 0)) { // How to access `this.acceptZero()`
        throw Error('Cannot accept zero.')
    }

    return number1 + number2
}

export default function myPackage(number1: number, number2: number, acceptZero: boolean = true): number {
    return add(number1, number2, acceptZero)
}
```

### Conclusion

I don't know how to approach this. One options is to pass all the config options in each function, but I don't like that approach, since it makes it harder to unit test all the functions independently. Besides, I don't think that would be a great solution at all.

Answer (score 0):

I asked this same question on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/1691nce/how_do_i_handle_user_configuration_in_my_package/), and those answers were very useful.

This is the final option I'm going for, and in my eyes it's the cleanest.

I created a `Config` singleton class that contains all default options. Every function can access the options from this `Config` singleton class, and the public function can set those options for the other functions to use.

Here's an example of how that might work (note that this isn't the actual code I'm using):

```js
export default class Config {
    private static instance: Config
    
    private options { {key:string]: any }: {}
    
    public static getInstance(): Config {
        if (!Config.instance) {
            Config.instance = new Config()
        }
    
        return Config.instance
    }
    
    get(key: string): any {
        return this.options[key]
    }
    
    set(key: string, value: any): void {
        this.options[key] = value
    }
}
```